# Unity3d Sprite Look broken in real device

Tags: android, rendering, sprite, unity-game-engine

i don't know why sprite UI Button look good In unity And Also I tested in MEmu Android emulator work nice , But when i tested in my phone it look like it's broken or something - see the image to understand

Thank You 
[image: Click Here to Understand]

Comment: Could it be that your background and button are on the same z-axis? Sometimes textures go through eachother when they're in the same position

Comment: How are you drawing your UI?  Are you using the built-in UI from unity for it? or are you using sprites and quads for it?  If it is the UI system from Unity then z fighting seems unlikely.

Comment: Thank you Ivar Bouwman and Eddge for Reply - Yes I'm using Unity Ui System GameObject > UI > Button then i replace default sprite by this , for z-axis i don't know i chek it  . Thanks

Comment: Now i tested in SG S3 with android 4.3 It work , the probleme only in my phone SG Trend plus with android 4.2.2

Comment: I fix'it by changing the image Sprite by another and it work